# Let's nuke the "error-message" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We have a tag named [error-message](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error-message), with now <s>220</s> <s>95</s> 49 questions tagged.

This is quite the meta tag, because it doesn't *mean* anything and adds no value to a question. Most problems result in some kind of error message, and if you get an error message with a certain program, just tag the question with that program.

Shall we get rid of it?

If anyone wants to do some manual cleanup, just [go through the tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error-message), and remove it from the questions. Watch out for other bad tags, and fix the post as well if there's anything to fix (e.g. bad titles, "Thanks", and the usual). If you see anything that should be closed and/or deleted, flag away. Please perform edits in smaller batches of 10–20 questions. Doing more will flood the front page unnecessarily.

A manual cleanup—at least a partial one—would be useful to spot bad content, which I'm sure is a little correlated with the use of bad tags.

Comment: What happens when a user tries to use the tag after we nuke it?

Comment: If the user has more than 300 reputation, the tag will be created again. We could of course ask the team to blacklist the tag, which I guess would make sense in this case. This would mean it can't be created anymore.

Comment: Some of those questions are actually about error messages, not errors (like "how to turn off xyz error message", not "I got this error, how do I fix it?"). What would we do with those?

Comment: @cpast The error message still appears in a certain program, so it should be sufficient to tag it with that. Think about it: Would anybody ever follow `error-message`, because they're an expert in… error messages? :)

Comment: Could you edit the question to update the "in reverse order" link? The questions are now reduced to a single page's worth.

Comment: Done. Good job of the community going through all these!

Comment: Does anybody actually measure if these changes actually improve the findability/popularity of the questions in search engines?  Consider, might some of these questions have been found with queries including "error message" that may no longer match?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea To my knowledge such aspects haven't been measured yet. But I'm very confident that it doesn't have a negative impact – if you search for the actual error message, that will already give you very precise results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All questions that had the tag have been retagged to get rid of it.