# Is application-error an error?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

We have a tag, [application-error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/application-error), with 79 questions.  Since a good percentage of software questions could be labeled "application error", it is not only meta, but does nothing to differentiate anything.  Can we nuke it?

Comment: Yes, please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deed is done.  All gone.

Answer (score 6):

**I say burninate [application-error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/application-error).**

Super User has a long-standing tradition of burninating error-related tags. I see no reason to break this tradition now.

- [error](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error): [What could we do with the [error] tag?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3736/what-could-we-do-with-the-error-tag)
- [errors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/errors): [Burninate error, errors, fatal error](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3942/burninate-error-errors-fatal-error)
- [error-message](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error-message): [Let's nuke the "error-message" tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6184/lets-nuke-the-error-message-tag)
- [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/problem): [Are "error" and "problem" meta-tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1648/are-error-and-problem-meta-tags) & [Please burninate the [problem] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3068/please-burninate-the-problem-tag)

Comment: I probably should have included this in the question.  :-)